# Using Nix on macOS how to install Python with pip?

Tags: python-3.x, nix

`nix-env -iA nixpkgs.python3Full`

does not install pip3

`nix-env -iA nixpkgs.python310Packages.pip`

> pip3 list
> Package Version
>
> ---
>
> pip     22.2.2
> Logging error ---
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/nix/store/6qxg1v3fvwr14llmkwyxxzdqvfz34m8s-python3.10-pip-22.2.2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/logging.py", line 177, in emit
> self.console.print(renderable, overflow="ignore", crop=False, style=style)
> File "/nix/store/6qxg1v3fvwr14llmkwyxxzdqvfz34m8s-python3.10-pip-22.2.2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/rich/console.py", line 1673, in print
> extend(render(renderable, render_options))
> File "/nix/store/6qxg1v3fvwr14llmkwyxxzdqvfz34m8s-python3.10-pip-22.2.2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/rich/console.py", line 1305, in render
> for render_output in iter_render:
> File "/nix/store/6qxg1v3fvwr14llmkwyxxzdqvfz34m8s-python3.10-pip-22.2.2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/logging.py", line 134, in **rich_console**
> for line in lines:
>
> .../...
> File "/nix/store/70c1n7i4c90dn4iys0myy30yfxmlsza7-python3-3.10.8/lib/python3.10/logging/**init**.py", line 968, in handle
> self.emit(record)
> File "/nix/store/6qxg1v3fvwr14llmkwyxxzdqvfz34m8s-python3.10-pip-22.2.2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/logging.py", line 179, in emit
> self.handleError(record)
> Message: '[present-rich] %s'
> Arguments: (UpgradePrompt(old='22.2.2', new='22.3.1'),)

Comment: Do you really have to install Pip?  You can just get a Python3 environment with your desired packages by doing something like this:  `nix-shell -p 'python3.withPackages (p: [ p.smbus2 ])'`  (replace smbus2 with the package you want).  Maybe this page will help you out:  https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Python

Comment: Thanks! But how do I do the same using nix-env -iA ?